# DebugDiag shows many HttpContext as not completed?

Tags: asp.net, iis, debugdiag

I took a process dump on a w3wp worker process, and I see too many HttpContext objects in the HttpContext Report

```
HttpContext Report

HttpContext Timeout Completed RunningSince ThreadId ReturnCode Verb RequestPath+QueryString 
cb7ac668a0 110 Sec  No 36797 Sec --- 200 GET XXXXX  
cb7ac6d670 2147483647 Sec  No 36673 Sec --- 200 GET YYYYY  
cb7ac916a8 110 Sec  No 8132 Sec --- 200 GET XXXXX  
cb7ac98500 110 Sec  No 8126 Sec --- 200 GET XXXXX  
cb7ac992b8 110 Sec  No 8106 Sec --- 200 GET XXXXX  
cb7aca21b0 110 Sec  No 8096 Sec --- 200 GET XXXXX  
cb7acad238 110 Sec  No 8086 Sec --- 200 GET XXXXX  
cb7acb6130 110 Sec  No 8076 Sec --- 200 GET XXXXX
```

The XXXXX is really just getting an ASP (classic) page in the directory for a healthcheck, but in the 15 hours since IIS has been running, it's accumulated over 3k of these. How do I clear out these HttpContext objects?

Also for the REST service that's hosted on the server YYYYY, for some reason the timeout is set to 2147483647 Sec (68 years?!?!). I don't see any settings in the web.config file to specify this. Any ideas?